Подскажите это нормальное явление в теге <a> ссылка на телегу а меня перекидывает в директорию с файлом html

a href="t.me/mo7kwa">t.me/account</a


в у меня есть тег а в нём ссылка на телегу при нажатии на ссылку меня перекидывает в корневую директорию где лежит файл html
file:///d%3A/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/site3/t.me/account

это нормально? при разработке сайта я не знаю как это будет работать когда всё будет на сервере лежать ?


Да, потому что что вы забыли указать протокол. Правильная ссылка https://t.me/mo7kwa

Добро пожаловать на сайт Дима Остроумов. Ознакомьтесь пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask как задать вопрос на ru.SO полезная ссылка


это нормальное явление в теге  ссылка на телегу а меня перекидывает в директорию с файлом html

Может быть нормальным, но в твоём случае - нет.

href="t.me/mo7kwa"


Это работать не будет. Ссылка относительная. надо так:
href="//t.me/mo7kwa"

но при открытии по file:// работать не будет, только на сайте.
Если зачем-то надо и так, и так, то только полностью с протоколом.
href="https://t.me/mo7kwa"

